# NetSuite: Setting Fulfill=false for item fulfillment line items

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

Using **suitescript 2.0**, Is it possible to transform a sales order into an item fulfillment and set the fulfill = false, like you can in the UI. This so I can save it, get the id. I want to prevent it from telling me

```
'You must enter at least one line item for this transaction'
```

when we don't know what the line items will be yet. For example we have a method called

```
CreateItemFulfillment(sales_order:string):number
```

Which transforms a sales order to IF and returns (or we want to return) the item fulfillment ID so it can be used down the line in the codebase

Comment: Assuming you create a new IF. Before saving it, what happens when you set the line items to `Fulfill = false`?

Comment: It gives the same ''You must enter at least one line item for this transaction'' error.

Comment: Did you try to put it in debug and see what  are you getting as line items ? Is there really any line item populating after the transformation ?

Comment: Yes done that and the default items are added automatically. I think im just going to have to use the transformation as soon as I call, I dont see any other way around and NetSuite support really sucks

Answer (score 0):

you can't save an item fulfillment record with 0 line item being selected. You need to select as least 1 line item. That's the error that's being returned.